# Puppeteer - why is innerText not printed on console while every element does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to access `innerText` of a list of `8` `els` (elements).
When I map over `els` and `console.log(el)` I see `8` elements neatly printed in my console of browser.
But when I `console.log(el.innerText)` I am getting just `3` or `4` texts printed out in my console.

I don't understand, what is happening here?

```js
  // wait for all cards to appear on page
  await page.waitForSelector(".card.cardItem:nth-of-type(8)", { timeout: 0 });

  await page.$$eval(".card.cardItem", (els) => {
    els.map((el) => {
      // logs out 8 elements (all have innerText on webpage).
      console.log(el)

      // logs out innerText of only 3 elements. Why?
      console.log(el.innerText);
    });
  });
```

Comment: when you do `console.log(el)` can you see the innerText property and value there?
try doing `console.log(el, el.innerText)` to see which elements dont have innerText for easier debugging

Comment: @HarisBouchlis when I console.log(el, el.innerText) I see 8 elements and 3 strings logged. So it's either an element and text or an element and blank. The elements that don't log innerText actually do have innerText with text in it when I inspect in devTools properties tab.

Comment: Can you somehow post the html you are scraping, to try to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with using `textContent` instead. I don't understand why, but it works. I will keep question open as I'm still curious why `innerText` doesn't work here so if someone knows feel free to explain to us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).